# Android return to provious app that was running when intent fired

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android app that runs in the background (a music playing app) that occasionally requires input from the user.

There is a MainActivity that starts with the app is launched. The MainActivity then starts a core process that plays music. When the core process determines that input is needed, it creates a new intent for the input.

Now, if you then go back to the home screen and launch another app (let's call it App X), the music keeps playing in the background, which is what I want.

Now, let's say while you're in App X, my music app needs user input. The input activity pops up on the screen, and the user can enter the input, which is also what I want. However, when the input activity closes, the music app's MainActivity is then made the current activity on the screen. What I want is for it to go back to App X.

So from what I can tell, it looks like when the input activity is created, the stack is like:

- Music App's Input Activity
- My music app's MainActivity
- App X

But I want it to be:

- Music App's Input Activity
- App X
- My music app's MainActivity

How can I achieve that?

**Edit:**

I read the article that @marmor linked to, and I'm not sure that singleTop is the right choice. The article says:

> For example, suppose a task's back stack consists of root activity A
>   with activities B, C, and D on top (the stack is A-B-C-D; D is on
>   top). An intent arrives for an activity of type D. If D has the
>   default "standard" launch mode, a new instance of the class is
>   launched and the stack becomes A-B-C-D-D. However, if D's launch mode
>   is "singleTop", the existing instance of D receives the intent through
>   onNewIntent(), because it's at the top of the stack—the stack remains
>   A-B-C-D.

I actually need to be able to have multiple instances of the inputActivity stacked on top of each other. So, if the main activity is A and the inputActivity is B, and three input events occur, without the user answering any of them, the stack should be A-B-B-B. singleTop sounds like it would prevent this.

This is all assuming that my app was in the foreground when the last input event occurred. If AppX was in the foreground then it should be in the stack, below any  input activities that were started since it was last in the foreground. Or maybe in between my app's main activity and all input activities.

Examples:

A-(AppX)-B-B-B

or

A-B-B-(AppX)-B

Comment: if what you mean by **core process** is an Android service, then you can probably just use `getActivity().finish();` and Android will automatically switch back to App X. Using sticky service will keep your service going on in the background even when the application is shut down.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your input-activity and your main activity are sitting on the same `Task`, so when the input activity finishes, Android returns to the next one in the `Task` - the main activity.

Add the following line to your input-activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

e.g.:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".InputActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
        </activity>
```

You can read more about activity tasks here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

EDIT:

If you're concerned about having a stack of InputActivity > Main Activity (not sure how that's possible in your case), then you can go with:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

From the docs:

> Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other
>   activities into the task holding the instance. **The activity is
>   always the single and only member of its task.**

Comment: I read the document that you linked to. From what I read, I'm not sure that singleTop is what I want. See my edit above.

Comment: Ok, I tried adding android:launchMode="singleInstance" to the input activity's Activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml. It didn't make a difference. When the input activity finishes, it still goes back to my app's main activity instead of AppX.